# What is the difference between "don't" & "won't" in the given sentences?

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice, prepositions

Are these sentences different or same?

> 1. They **don't** let you smoke in here.
> 2. They **won't** let you smoke in here.

Also, is it necessary to use *in* in the sentences?
Would the meaning of sentences change if I do not use "in"? Can't I just say "They **don't** let you smoke here."?

Comment: I didn't understand your example on the Won't. **The Won't.**
> My classmates won't follow the rules. This suggests that there exists effort directed towards making the classmates follow rules. The phrasing gives an implication that there's an opposing force that's trying to behave your classmates. what does exists effort mean in your sentence? I like to comment, but 50 reputation error coming for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**I partially disagree with the two other answers (as of the time of this writing).**

### The *Don't*.

Let's use a slightly different example sentence to make the nuances clearer:

> My classmates don't follow the rules.

This means that the classmates have a general habit of not following the rules. It's form of [time-agnostic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnosticism) knowledge; it's possible that you're now attending another school and talking about ex-classmates.

### The *Won't*.

> My classmates won't follow the rules.

This suggests that there exists *effort* directed towards making the classmates follow rules. The phrasing gives an implication that there's an opposing force that's trying to behave your classmates.

### Your example.

> They don't let you smoke in here.

This is general; the speaker has probably deduced that from a no-smoking sign or similar.

> They won't let you smoke in here.

This would imply that the speaker has probably actually **tried** to smoke once and they didn't let him. You might end up getting the implication that he tried to convince them (*'oh, just this one cigarette'*), which is the *effort* we mentioned in our conceptualization.

**Note:** this is a pretty small and nuanced difference; nobody will get confused if you use them interchangeably, but it does come quite naturally for native speakers.

#### Lastly: the *In*.

Simple:

> It was getting crazy and hot in here.

This is **localized**; it was probably getting crazy in a room, hall, or some other enclosed 'cozy' place.

> It was getting violent here.

This is more **general** and can refer to any type of place that is more likely **abstractly-bordered-and-contained** than having brick-and-mortar walls; think countries and nations, school campuses, streets, etc.

Comment: Great explanation. I’m finally beginning to understand differences between don’t and won’t.

Comment: +1 Good explanation on "in". It implies some sort of definite, confined (in some way, by walls, barricades, etc.) area, _whether or not_ it's completely enclosed (i.e., it could be a courtyard). Without it, "here" is a hazy notion, more approximate in what it encloses, and could even encompass a small room. You would usually use "in here" talking about a room, and just "here" for an open field.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of speaking can also be

> You **can't** smoke in here.

Now, referring to the terms in your question.

> 1. They **don't** let you smoke in here.
> 2. They **won't** let you smoke in here.

The difference arises when talking about volition. In the first case, you may have been caught smoking and they might decide to let you go. On the other hand, if it is *won't* in the example, then you strictly are NOT allowed to smoke.

The usage of **can't** is like a request regarding the action.

As to your question regarding the usage of **in** in the sentences; by using **`in here`** you have restricted your domain to a particular region. If you just use `here` instead, then you are referring to nearby areas too.

For eg. suppose I'm using the following inside a room:

> - Don't you smoke **in here**.
> - Don't you smoke **here**.

In the first sentence, I am restricting my smoke-free area to the particular room and the people can go outside the room for smoking. But, in second case I have a larger area covered and it depends upon the understanding between the listener and speaker.